# Есть ли в pyqt что-то на подобие "Entry" из tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Всем привет!
Есть данный код, и по нажатию на кнопку должно отображаться введенное значение из текст-бокса, но этого не происходит:

```
#СОЗДАНИЕ ТЕКСТ БОКСА
textbox = QLineEdit(root)
textbox.move(220, 25)
textbox.resize(90, 20)
textbox2 = textbox.text()

#ФУНКЦИЯ, КОТОРАЯ ВЫВОДИТ ВВЕДЕННОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ИЗ ТЕКСТ БОКСА
def nameUserDef():
    Label(textbox2, 220, 200)

#КНОПКА ЗАПУСКАЮЩАЯ ФУНКЦИЮ, КОТОРАЯ ВЫВОДИТ ВВЕДЕННОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ИЗ ТЕКСТ БОКСА
Button('получить введенные данный', 220, 170, nameUserDef)
```

А вот тот же самый код, только я дописал туда это - `textbox.setText('привет')` и он прекрасно работает:

```
#СОЗДАНИЕ ТЕКСТ БОКСА
textbox = QLineEdit(root)
textbox.move(220, 25)
textbox.setText('привет')
textbox.resize(90, 20)
textbox2 = textbox.text()

#ФУНКЦИЯ, КОТОРАЯ ВЫВОДИТ ВВЕДЕННОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ИЗ ТЕКСТ БОКСА
def nameUserDef():
    Label(textbox2, 220, 200)

#КНОПКА ЗАПУСКАЮЩАЯ ФУНКЦИЮ, КОТОРАЯ ВЫВОДИТ ВВЕДЕННОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ИЗ ТЕКСТ БОКСА
Button('получить введенные данный', 220, 170, nameUserDef)
```

Т.е пока изначально в коде не задашь какое-нибудь строковое значение текст-боксу, он не будет выводить ничего..
Нельзя сделать так, чтобы выводилось значение тогда, когда ввел что-то в сам текст-бокс?

Спасибо.

Comment: Какой ужасный код не qt-шный код. У Qt свои обозначения элементов, и не стоит их смешивать с qt-шными или пытаться заменить. `Label` и `Button` похоже или объекты или функции, если функции, то фигово. Плюс комменты в верхнем регистре не питоничьи :) Да и ваш код не позволяет воспроизвести проблему у посторонних, да и не хватает тут кода, в котором и есть проблема

Comment: Как это? В пайтоне есть два вида комментариев # и '''

Comment: Вообще-то есть только #, кавычки нужны для хранения текста, в питоне есть pep8 и в нем описаны рекомендации по оформлению кода, если будете работать в PyCharm, то она сама вам подскажет как правильно оформить код, подсветив нужные куски кода, плюс очень удобная и клевая IDE

Comment: `Плюс комменты в верхнем регистре не питоничьи` а к чему тогда это замечание?

Comment: Не питон-стайл комменты :) Вот на русском: http://pep8.ru/doc/pep8/

Comment: Только не обижайтесь на критику, в целом она конструктивная :)

Answer (score 3):

Пример виджета с несколькими компонентами на форме.

Введенный в `line_edit` текст дублируется в `label`, а при клике на кнопку, показывается диалог с текстом из `line_edit`:

```
try:
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
        QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox
    )
except:
    from PyQt4.QtGui import (
        QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox
    )


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('My widget')

        self.label = QLabel()

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.textEdited.connect(self.label.setText)
        # # OR:
        # self.line_edit.textEdited.connect(lambda text: self.label.setText(text))

        self.push_button = QPushButton('Show text')
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.show_text_from_line_edit)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.push_button)
        layout.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def show_text_from_line_edit(self):
        text = self.line_edit.text()
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Info', text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]